# Not installable libreadline6 (>= 6.0) while instaling R 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.14 LTS

Tags: r

I use 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

When I try to install R-base-core:

```
sudo apt install r-base-core
```

I see:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
```

I have done:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But the problem remains

Comment: That package is currently only available in xenial (16.04).  I can't recall the reason why sorry, and what was plan with it..  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libreadline6

Comment: @guiverc And what to do?

Comment: How do you plan to install R? Please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base-core`. Do you really need 3.6.2?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my etc/apt/sources.list file. It had the same repository repeated. I deleted two lines and the problem was solved.